# Pass file handle by number on Windows

Tags: winapi, ipc, file-descriptor

On Unix-like operating systems, the file descriptors (file handles) used for things like pipes and sockets are small integers. It's common for a parent process to communicate with its child process by opening a pipe, socket or file at a particular file descriptor number. The number will either be agreed upon by the programmers of the parent and child program, or passed to the child program via the command line or environment variables. The child can then access the inherited file descriptor using the same number as the parent.

Is there a convention for passing handle numbers in a similar way on Windows? As far as I can tell, the relevant MSDN articles only talk about such conventions for the "standard" file handles (standard input, standard output, standard error). What would be a robust and idiomatic way to do something like "pass a pipe on file descriptor 3" as we sometimes do on Unix?

The [MSDN article on Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/inheritance) says (emphasis mine):

> An inherited handle refers to the same object in the child process as it does in the parent process. It also **has the same value** and access privileges.

Does this mean that I can just cast the `HANDLE` value to an integer, convert that integer into a string and pass that string as a command line argument for the child process to parse and get the same handle back, and is this reliable or customary? Is there some other IPC mechanism that Windows programmers would normally use instead?

The main motivation for me would be to avoid temporary files and use pipes instead. This is conventional when all you have is stdin/stdout but less so when you have multiple pipes.

Comment: It is okay, but you have to cast to (long long).  Handles are 64-bit values on x64.  Just keep the other consequences in mind, this is hard to test and debug.

Comment: _"pass a pipe on file descriptor 3"_ - create a pipe with a unique name (e. g. by using a GUID) and pass the name of the pipe to the child process, by command-line parameter. The child process can use `CreateFile` to open the pipe by name. This avoids the problem that Hans mentioned aswell as other problems (cases where you can't inherit handles, e. g. when you have to use `ShellExecuteEx`).